# Is there a way to clear empty array in c++ , check code below for explanation

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

```
generated = (rand() % 11);

cout << "GUESS THE NUMBER 10 TIMES" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  cin >> guesses[i];

  if (generated == guesses[i]) {
    cout << "CONGRATS ! YOU HAVE FOUND THE CORRECT NUMBER ! " << generated << endl;
    restart();
    break;
  }
}
cout << "HERE ARE YOUR GUESSES:" << endl;
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
  cout << guesses[k] << endl;
}
```

If the array isn't filled up, the output gives me the guessed values and then in the empty slots are random numbers.  Is there a way to clear or delete the untouched slots?

Comment: Arrays have fixed size so there will always be values present; there is no such thing as an "empty" array, unless you mean an array of size 0. I suggest using `std::vector` isntead.

Comment: The array contains garbage because elements have not first been properly initialized. _Unlike C# or Java, arrays are not "zero'd" by default_. Alternatives if an array "must" be used: 1) keep a manual *count* of how many items have been added, and only iterate that many times so non-initialized elements are never read; 2) initialize all the array elements by filling in a sentinel value (such as -1), then stop iterating when reading a sentinel value _or_ reaching the end of the array, which ever is first.

Comment: Where's the definition of `guesses` though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Keep a count of how many inputs you take `c` and loop up to `c` instead of 10 in your second loop:

```
int c = 0;
cout << "GUESS THE NUMBER 10 TIMES" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cin >> guesses[i];
    c++;

    if (generated == guesses[i]) {
        cout << "CONGRATS ! YOU HAVE FOUND THE CORRECT NUMBER ! " << generated << endl;
        restart();
        break;
    }
}
cout << "HERE ARE YOUR GUESSES:" << endl;
for (int k = 0; k < c; k++)
    cout << guesses[k] << endl;
```

Comment: Definitely check out std:: vector. It will do this bookkeeping for you. This seems like a good tutorial https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/06/21/an-introduction-to-stdvector/